# Need to stop execution of javascript method until cgi response is received

Tags: javascript, html, forms, cgi, cgi-bin

I am working on a web app in which I am calling cgi-bin from backhand.I use ajax request for that.Now I want one scenario in which I want to wait till the cgi response is arrived.Actually one form action is called which is also a cgi.
now I am able to do the task but method returns first and cgi response is received later.Depending on cgi response action needs to be called.
Is it possible ?
Please help...
Thanks in advance...
Here is the code I am using :-

```
var flag = "";
if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 0){        
        xmlHttpReq.open('POST', destinationURL, true);
        xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4) {                
                if(xmlHttpReq.responseText == "OK"){
                    flag = true;
                }
                else{        
                    flag = false;
                }
            }            
        }
        xmlHttpReq.send();

    }
    return flag;
```

Now I want to call form action only when the flag true,calling this function in button onclick event with type = "submit".

Comment: You can do ajax requests synchronously.  Is that all you need?

Comment: I am doing so but even though I am not getting as expected output..

Answer (score 0):

keep the first response in a global variable, and for the second call, if it's dependent on the first one, just wait...

As **I hate cross browser problems**, here is the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) version:

```
$("form").submit(function() {

    // let's get what we need
    $.ajax({
        url: destinationURL,
        context: document.body,
        async: false, // you want a synchronous call
        success: function(){
          // done
        },
        error: function() { alert('something went wrong...'); }
    });

    // Continue your work, the line below will only be processed
    //   after the $.ajax call is made

});
```